# When HttpModule Init method runs in ASP.NET Integrated mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, iis-7, httpmodule

I've written an HttpModule that is an NHibernate Session Provider. It simply opens a SessionFactory in Init method of HttpModule and gets a new Session in BeginRequest and closes it in EndRequest. At the other side, I wrote a method in Global.asax that uses a session from this HttpModule named GetData. I run that method (GetData) in Init method of Global.asax. The problem is when I use my HttpModule in integrated mode it seems that my HttpModule does not Initialize before running Init method of Global.asax.

I've searched for order of running these methods and life cycle of events but nothing useful found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET does not provide any guarantees on when HttpModule Init() methods are called with respect to one another (not unlike static initializers). In general, the Init() methods should be used to wire up event handlers, and any "real work" should be done in the event handlers.

All registered event handlers for a specific event are called from all HttpModules, including Global.asax, before moving on to the next event -- so you have control over order that way.

Answer (score 3):

In IIS 7.x, modules and handlers should be registered within `system.webServer` xml element in your `web.config` file.

Check this MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Comment: I know that. I used this syntax for registering modules in integrated mode. That's not the problem.

Comment: @alisabzevari Then check IIS config. Anyway, it's hard to assist you taking your question's info...